# SQL Server 2005 problem with ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ...)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

This question is in relation to a previous question I've asked ... see "SQL Server 2005 How to order a recordset when using the LIKE operator".

The following works ...

```
with xx as
(
select  case
    when mycol = 'finance' then 1
    when mycol like 'finance%' then 2
    when mycol like '%finance%' then 3
    end as rnk, 
    *
from    MyTable
where   mycol like '%finance%'
)

select * from xx 
order by xx.rnk, xx.mycol;
```

But what I really want to do is this, as I'm using the server to page through records ...

```
WITH xx AS
(
select  case
    when t.term = 'finance' then 1
    when t.term like 'finance%' then 2
    when t.term like '%finance%' then 3
    end as rnk, 
    *, 
    row_number() over (order by rnk, t.term) as rownumber
from    tblTerms t
where   t.term like '%finance%'
)

select * from xx 
where rownumber between 11 and 20 -- page #2
order by xx.rnk, xx.mycol;
```

I'm getting an error " Invalid column name 'rnk' ".

Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Many thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the common table expression (CTE) definition.  You can't reference `rnk` in the same SELECT clause where the column alias is defined.  You can try this:

```
WITH xx AS
(
select  case
    when t.term = 'finance' then 1
    when t.term like 'finance%' then 2
    when t.term like '%finance%' then 3
    end as rnk, 
    *
from    tblTerms t
where   t.term like '%finance%'
),

yy AS
(
SELECT *,
    row_number() over (order by rnk, term) as rownumber
FROM xx
)

select * from yy 
where rownumber between 11 and 20 -- page #2
order by yy.rnk, yy.mycol;
```

Comment: Thanks bobs. I copied and pasted your answer into my query window and still get error msg ... Invalid column name 'rnk'. 

So I removed the row_number() from the with xx statement and the yy.mycol from the last order by and that fixed it ... now I get the results I want. Many thanks!

Comment: @Mark, sorry about the mistake.  You made the right fix.  I'll correct it for other viewers.